# Java Flight Recorder throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, jfr

Java Flight Recorder throws IO error:

> Could not download recording for My Recording.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: No chunks

Screenshot:
http://s016.radikal.ru/i334/1609/86/02219bfb4c69.png

I use these JVM flags:

```
java -jar ^
-server ^
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures ^
-XX:+FlightRecorder ^
-XX:StartFlightRecording=delay=5s,duration=40s,name=myrecording,filename=C:\JFR\1.jfr ^
 tool.jar
```

Comment: Its not an issue with your arguments, your code is trying to reading a file and it hasn't found. Try to put question in an appropriate way, paste the code so that others can help you.

Comment: @harshavmb what code? JFR has completed task and is trying to save file with results to somename.jfr, but can't. My program works well.

Comment: Your question is very unclear and it is very difficult to predict what is wrong at your end. Try to put as much details as you can in a concise way else you get negative score from fellow users like this.

Comment: @harshavmb done

Comment: Does C:\JFR\1.jfr ^tool.jar really exists in C:\JFR\ directory? I don' think 1.jfr ^tool.jar is the correct file name.

Comment: @harshavmb ^ is cmd feature for comfortable reading commands. I think 1.jfr should be automaticaly generated, but now it exists in that directory with 0 bytes after unlucky runs. http://s48.radikal.ru/i122/1609/85/74cedde47776.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without delay=5s?

You may get an error message on standard out if you start the recording directly. You can also try to start with:

-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=loglevel=trace

to get more information when it starts the recording.

Answer (score 0):

Your user name, and therefore your temporary directory, contains characters that are not in the 7-bit ASCII set, which seems to confuse Flight Recorder. I've had the same issue with Swedish characters in user names on Windows.

In my case problem was solved when I set the TMP environment variable to a path with only plain characters.